# Change the location of the public(www) Apache folder on debian 8

Tags: linux, apache, web, debian, public-html

I am facing a peculiar problem with apache2 running on debian 8. I followed a couple of tutorials to install it and everything worked great. The problem is that i have partitioned the disk as 9gb for the system files, 1gb swap and 30gb for the home folder so I wanted to move the www folder from it's current location (/var/www) to home(/home/www). 
I found more than a few guides on how to do that, some saying that i should change the lines in apache2.conf from this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

to this:

```
<Directory /home/paul/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

As well as the documentRoot

Others suggested using the 000-default.conf file located in the /etc/apache2/sites-available folder and change the default folder from /var/www to /home/paul/www.

I did both and the folder was seen but not accessible, so i used the quick solution and use chroot 777. After that apache redirected me back to /var/www. 
All settings point to /home/paul/www and the www folder has full read write permission. In fact neither the apache.conf nor 000-sites-available has any reference of /var/www so why does apache keep pointing me there? Is there something i missed?

p.s i did updates and upgrades multiple times as well as restarted the apache service and the entire pc.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the ownership of files to allow apache there
please try

`chown -R www-data  /home/paul/www/`

however if you set a particion for your paul www why not mount the partition in /var/www

or you can create a symlink

`ln -s /home/paul/www /var/www/paulsite`

then edit your apache conf accordingly.

Regarding the edited file I recomend you use the 000-default better. in fact i would use that as a skeletone. and create a new file for your site then enable that site.

Comment: I already did your first suggestion. The folder www and all it's contents have full read write permissions. I will try the symlink suggestion which looks very promising.

Comment: could you post your /etc/fstab to check how you are mounting the partition?

Comment: nevermind. I got it with a different method. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so with a little research i realized that what i was trieing to do was not the best practice at all! (Thanx for the heads up Sudakatux).
I found the solution in [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14301/apache-symlinked-to-home-directory-permission-errors) for anyone interested.

Instead of trieing to change the mechanics of apache i enabled the userdir module and set up public_html in my home folder with 755 permissions. I use a redirection script from the initial location to the various locations on my home directory. Works just fine!